# Forçar o usuário a responder uma alternativa válida em um sistema de perguntas de multipla escolha em Python

Tags: python, loop, operadores, dicionário, iterator

O código abaixo funciona bem, porém gostaria que ele fizesse a pergunta especificada novamente caso o usuário não digitar uma das três alternativas disponíveis.

```
perguntas = {
    'Pergunta 1': {
        'pergunta': 'Quanto é 2+2? ',
        'respostas': {'a': '1', 'b': '4', 'c': '5',},
        'resposta_certa': 'b'
    },
    'Pergunta 2': {
        'pergunta': 'Quanto é 5*3? ',
        'respostas': {'a': '10', 'b': '40', 'c': '15',},
        'resposta_certa': 'c'
    },
}

respostas_certas = 0

for pk, pv in perguntas.items():
    print(f'{pk}: {pv["pergunta"]}')

    print('Respostas: ')
    for rk, rv in pv['respostas'].items():
        print(f'[{rk}]: {rv}')
    
    resposta_usuario = input('Sua resposta: ')

    if resposta_usuario == pv['resposta_certa']:
        print('Certa a Resposta!')
        respostas_certas +=1
    else:
        print('Resposta errada!')

    print()

qtd_perguntas = len(perguntas)
porcentagem_acerto = respostas_certas / qtd_perguntas * 100  

print(f'Você acertou {respostas_certas} respostas')
print(f'Sua porcentagem de acerto foi de {porcentagem_acerto}%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um pequeno laço `while` que continuamente pede pelo input do usuário até que ele digite uma das alternativas possíveis:

```
resposta_usuario = input('Sua resposta: ')
while resposta_usuario not in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
    resposta_usuario = input("Resposta inválida, digite apenas a, b ou c:")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.